# How to print every x, y pair used during a Tensorflow training model.fit(X, Y)?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to debug why two training operations behave differently whereas I feed them with the same data in a slightly different format: one time it's a `numpy.ndarray` and the other it's a `tensorflow.data.Dataset`.

What would help would be to log every pair `x`, `y` which is fed to the neural network during the training operation:

```
model.fit(X, Y, ...)  # X, Y and numpy ndarrays
model.fit(ds, ...)    # ds is a tensorflow.data.Dataset
```

**Question: how to ask Tensorflow to log every pair input/target that is used during training?** (both in the numpy ndarray or tensorflow Dataset case)

---

Note: I've looked at doing a custom `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback` like in [How can I output some data during a model.fit() run in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332169/how-can-i-output-some-data-during-a-model-fit-run-in-tensorflow/60340008#60340008) but unfortunately the `on_train_batch_begin` method doesn't expose the actual batch data / training data itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `train_step` for the purpose.

Example Codes:

```
class printeverybatch(tf.keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data
        tf.print('new batch:')
        tf.print(x,summarize=-1)
        tf.print(y,summarize=-1)
        return super().train_step(data)

tf.random.set_seed(88883)
np.random.seed(88883)

inputs=tf.keras.Input((5,))
model=printeverybatch(inputs,tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs))

x=np.random.rand(4,5)
y=np.random.rand(4,1)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD())
model.fit(x,y,batch_size=2,verbose=2,epochs=2)
'''
Epoch 1/2
new batch:
[[0.227194726 0.271517038 0.27261427 0.577692807 0.100502096]
 [0.535813034 0.298211783 0.669178188 0.989641547 0.383945227]]
[[0.392579]
 [0.275484771]]
new batch:
[[0.494236499 0.969957471 0.500168502 0.537253439 0.768969536]
 [0.243241057 0.0589612834 0.78992331 0.718339801 0.0696426481]]
[[0.20291324]
 [0.497432947]]
2/2 - 0s - loss: 1.2453
Epoch 2/2
new batch:
[[0.535813034 0.298211783 0.669178188 0.989641547 0.383945227]
 [0.243241057 0.0589612834 0.78992331 0.718339801 0.0696426481]]
[[0.275484771]
 [0.497432947]]
new batch:
[[0.494236499 0.969957471 0.500168502 0.537253439 0.768969536]
 [0.227194726 0.271517038 0.27261427 0.577692807 0.100502096]]
[[0.20291324]
 [0.392579]]
2/2 - 0s - loss: 1.0387
'''
```

It will work for both `numpy.ndarray` and `tensorflow.data.Dataset`.

**Edit:** To convert an existing `tf.keras.Model` or `tf.keras.Sequential` to the new model subclass, `printeverybatch`:

```
model_print=printeverybatch(existing_model.input,existing_model.output)
#if existing_model is already compiled,
model_print.compile(optimizer=existing_model.optimizer,loss=existing_model.loss)
```

By doing this, you will have two versions of models, i.e., `model_print` will print `x`,`y` every batch during fit and `existing_model` will not. The two models share the same underlying layers, their connections and parameters, and model optimizer's states.

Comment: Thank you! How to do this on an existing sequential Model? `model = Sequential(); model.add(Dense(50, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(784,))); ...`

Comment: @Basj You can do this to convert an existing model: `model=printeverybatch(model.input,model.output)`. If you want to undo it afterwards, do this: `model=tf.keras.Model(model.input,model.output)`

Comment: After doing these conversion, the model needs to be compiled again and the optimizer's instance needs to be the same to preserve optimizer's state if there's any.

Comment: Thank you @LaplaceRicky for your answer. For future reference, maybe can you edit the answer to include an example code with `Sequential` to show what you explained in your 2 last comments?